# image won't load in the first time ionic

Tags: lazy-loading, ionic-framework

I have a problem in my ionic application, when I load my page the first time the images are not displayed all
I need to change the page and return for finding the images displayed.
Can someone help me?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

just my opinion, if that problem occurs when you trying to debug in emulator/device(ionic run/ ionic emulate).. you just need to add following code

**ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**

from your terminal into your project folder.

Regards